# IdeaVim doesn't load .vimrc?

Tags: pycharm, ideavim

I am using the latest ideaVim (0.32) with PyCharm 3.1 on OS X 10.9.2. I have several key mappings in ~/.vimrc but non of them seem to be read by ideaVIM. From the update log of ideaVIM I think it is supposed to load a subset of .vimrc files and it definitely should support key remapping.

For example I explicitly tested to have the single line below in my ~/.vimrc and ideaVIM doesn't seem to be reading it at all.

```
nmap <Space> i
```

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: I believe you will get better response if you ask such question in actual IdeaVim tracker (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM?q=vimrc) or actual ticket (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-288). Check comments and search for existing tickets first.

Comment: Never mind I just found my version is simply too old. They just updated to 0.33 in the plugin repo today.

Comment: I have inoremap jj <Esc> in my ~/.vimrc but its not working. How did u get it to work?

Comment: I don't think they actually support mapping consecutive key strokes to a command.

Answer (score 22):

As of version 0.35 (IdeaVim):

~/.vimrc is no longer read by default, use ~/.ideavimrc instead

Comment: And you can put `source ~/.vimrc` in it if you want to use existing settings.

Answer (score 0):

Just like I said in the comment, it's version 0.33 that supports this feature. 0.32 simply doesn't support it :)